# calculate different statistics for multi-dimensional numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

There exists an `nd.array` referred to as `label1`, when printing it out, it has

```
[[0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 88 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 ...,
 [0 0 1 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 2 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]]
```

Its shape is `(729,816)`. Are there any ways to know how many unique values are in this array? When running `print(np.where(label1==label1.max()))`, the result looks like this `(array([  0,   0,   0, ..., 234, 234, 234]), array([450, 451, 452, ..., 433, 434, 435]))`, does that mean it has two arrays (or two lines) have those maximum values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To get the sorted unique values in your array, do `numpy.unique(label1)`.
2. When called on a two-dimensional array, `numpy.where` returns two arrays which are the row and column coordinates of all matching entries. So, if `numpy.where` returns `(array([0]), array([1]))` it means that one match was found at row 0, column 1.

**EDIT:** If you want to extract and print the row and column coordinates from `numpy.where`, you can do it like this:

```
rows, cols = np.where(label1==label1.max())
for row, col in zip(rows, cols):
  print row, col
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. With respect to the example given, does that mean the matches are find at (row 0, column 450), (row 0, column 451), etc.  The print function cannot list those long arrays. Are there any way to print out or extract all of these positions in terms of (row column) combination?

Comment: Yes, it does. You have all the information you need to access those coordinates. See the edit to my post.